# How to properly stop Python script that calls infinite subprocess?

Tags: python

I have a python script that uses yt-dlp to download a video live stream. Because of the video format, yt-dlp is actually calling ffmpeg to make the download. However, the stream sometimes stops and web server sends 403 errors. This causes ffmpeg to stop recording. So I have a simple infinite loop that keeps trying to download the file, if it fails - sleeps for 10 seconds and tries again. And then I catch keyboard interrupt and set loop to false, terminating the script.

All works fine, except there's a gotcha - the first time I press Ctrl+c I actually don't kill the script, I stop the ffmpeg downloader. So if I press Ctrl+c very quickly, the loop will just come back to the beginning and will start download again. However, if I press and hold Ctrl+c, then the ffmpeg script will stop and then the python script will catch the keyboard interrupt and stop.This is not an issue if I run it locally, but I actually wanted to be able to launch it remotely from a web browser. I've found the project script-server that seems to do what I need, except - I can't terminate the script because of this stupid behavior.

So the question is - any idea how I could catch the keyboard interrupt properly in the main yt-dlp script without it getting caught by the ffmpeg first? Or any other ideas how I could make this python script react normally to the Ctrl+c? Part of the problem is - I need to gracefully shut down ffmpeg, as it needs to finish up processing the file to avoid data loss.
Relevant code block:

```
while LOOP:
    ydl_opts = {
    "hls_use_mpegts" : True,
    "hls_prefer_native" : False,
    "outtmpl" : f"{datetime.now():%Y%m%d_%H%M%S%z}-{EVENT_NAME}.ts",
    "quiet": True
    }
    try:
        ydl = YoutubeDL(ydl_opts)
        ydl.download(URLS)

    except utils.DownloadError:
        print(f"Download error, retrying in {SLEEP_FOR} seconds")
        time.sleep(SLEEP_FOR)

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        LOOP = False
```

EDIT:
I got it working, but it's very messy. The daemon method worked in Windows, but failed in Linux. The final version that works with script-server in Linux has the following block above the loop:

```
def sigterm_handler(s, frame):
    global LOOP
    LOOP = False
    p = os.getpid()
    os.kill(p, signal.SIGINT)

signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, sigterm_handler)
```

So basically I am catching sigterm from the script-server, then sending sigint to the script itself, which is being received by the ffmpeg that makes a graceful shutdown. And then I am also setting loop to false, making sure it doesn't start again. Very ugly, but seems to be reliable.

Comment: Instead of describing your code, show us the relevant parts!

Comment: @KlausD. Sure thing, but there's really not much to it. Added to original post

Comment: Does `ydl` have some method which tells it to stop? If so, then call this method when handling `KeyboardInterrupt`.

Comment: By default, Ctrl-C should be received _both_ by the Python script and any subprocess like `ffmpeg`.  If `yt-dlp` is suppressing that behavior (and perhaps turning the interrupt into a `DownloadError`), it should document what happens in that case.

Comment: @DavisHerring I understand that it should, but it isn't. It does not turn it into any error, it just stops the download (ffmpeg takes a little bit of time, maybe half a second or less) and then the loop resumes.

Comment: @mkrieger1 Again - the initial Ctlr-C does not get registered by my script at all. I have to press and hold it in order for it to register (and then the script stops as expected).

Comment: You need to make a daemon. Check this [Github issue](https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp/issues/5902).